# Rails to_json with all relations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, activerecord, has-many

I have an Item class that also contains many items (using has_many). What I want to do is read all items that have no parent (the top level) and all their subitems. So basically I need my entire Item table nested correctly, into json.

This is the code I'm using right now, but this only returns the top level items and their items, it doesn't go any lower than that. (So I'm left with only two levels)

```
@items = Item.where("item_id IS ?" , nil).order("position")
respond_to do |format|
  format.json { render :json => @items.to_json(:include => :items)}
end
```

Comment: did you know the rabl gem? i think you can use it. https://github.com/nesquena/rabl

Comment: Item class that also contains many items ?

Comment: @shiva yes. So basically for each item I'm able to do Item.first.items

Comment: Can you post the result of `select * from item`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I **do not suggest override as_json or to_json**.

The reason is you'll need the raw data elsewhere, and you may need data in other format. Manipulate `as_json` will finally change the data, and you have no way to extend.

Using a decorator is the way to go. A good choice the gem [ActiveModel Serializers](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers). Basically it work like this

```
class ItemSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :title, :body
  has_many :comments # The JSON output will have comments inside.
end
```

And then in your controller:

```
@items = Item.where("item_id IS ?" , nil).order("position")
respond_to do |format|
  format.json { render :json => @items }
end
```

Your `@items` will be serialized by ItemSerializer automatically.

Or you can choose a custom serializer

```
render json: @items, each_serializer: ItemWithAssociatedSerializer
```

Comment: overriding `as_json` the way i did it just changes the defaults, so you can always go back to previous behavior by passing in arguments `to to_json`. Anyway, using a serializer is better (i used as_json because this is the officially recommended method), so you're right :)

Answer (score 0):

First, I would recommend using a gem like [ancestry](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry) or [awesome nested set](https://github.com/collectiveidea/awesome_nested_set). It will help you manage your Items tree structure efficiently (retrieving a whole hierarchy in one SQL query, and so on).

then you can do something like this :

```
class Item
  def as_json(options={})
    super({include: items}.merge options)
  end
end
```

this means that calling `to_json` on an item would by default include the children's json ; so recursively we go down the whole hierarchy.

If you need a way to limit the number of nested levels, you can do :

```
class Item
  def as_json(options={})
    return super({include: items}.merge options) unless options[:depth].present?
    if options[:depth] > 0 
      super({include: items, depth: options[:depth] - 1}.merge options)
    else
      super
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work (or do I need to install the gems first?) This is actually the only such case in my application and I don't need many options but I'll have a look at those gems if they make life easier. Thanks!

Comment: sorry, did not test that. What does not work ? the first or the second solution ?

Comment: ouch, typo. `includes` => `ìnclude`

Comment: btw, the gem is optional. It's only a way to store and manage tree structures in you database more efficiently (as we use recursion, we may have a lot of subsequent queries: one for each leaf node !)